# How can one show that $\frac{d}{dt}\langle x^2\rangle = \frac{1}{m}(\langle xp \rangle+\langle px\rangle )$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

I am trying to prove that for an unidimensional system

$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x^2\rangle  = \frac{1}{m}(\langle xp \rangle+\langle px\rangle )$$

where $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$. This is my first course on QM so I am a bit lost, how can this be done?

Comment: Hello Ramon, since on this site "do my homework"-questions are off-topic and therefore wont be answered I recommend you to edit your question as follows:
choose a title which is somewhat describing your problem,
show what you do know and what you have tried and which concept you do not understand.

Comment: Hint-use Ehrenfest's theorem

Answer (score 3):

In the Heisenberg picture,
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}
\langle\psi|x^2|\psi\rangle
& =
\left\langle\psi\middle|\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}x^2\middle|\psi\right\rangle
\\ & =
\frac{i}{\hbar}
\left\langle\psi\middle|\left[H,x^2\right]\middle|\psi\right\rangle
.
\end{align}
The commutator comes down to a multiple of $\left[p^2,x^2\right]$, which can be solved using repeated application of $[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C]$ and $[x,p]=i\hbar$.

The rest is for you to do.